# Find the word and replace at the end of each line

Tags: notepad++

I have few requirement,

I have multiple columns, where I need to replace the column name with the following,

`Ex. "Month" = s."Month"`

Column name is month, I want to append as columname = s.columnname.

I want to do regex in notepad++.

I tried with following,

for appending at end of line I used find- $.

not sure what should be used in replace - =s.

How to get the value of columnname using notepad++.

If 1 column I can use month as it is, but it has multiple columns how to get the value as it is and place it..

Please help me out..

Thanks

I tried in find tab used $

I am expecting what should be used in replace tab in notepad++ as below

```
column name     Replace with
MONTH          MONTH=s."MONTH"
WEEK           WEEK=s."WEEK"
Call           Call=s."call"
DATE           DATE=s."DATE"
STATUS         STATUS=s."STATUS"
```

Comment: Please include sample data.

Comment: added the image of output required

Comment: Please do not use images, please show input and output as text.

Comment: [Please post your data as text, not image.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/372239). Show input file and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to grap the last word in a group by surrounding it with round brackets.

```
(\w+)$
```

Than you can access to this group by using $1

```
$1=s."$1"
```

Original File:

```
Day
Month
Year
```

After search and replace:

```
Day=s."Day"
Month=s."Month"
Year=s."Year"
```

Comment: Not working for me.. where can I add screenshot?

Comment: Did you activate the regular expression check box in the search and replace window?

Comment: Yes I did that..it is putting the s."" not the value..I am doing in notepad++